# How to show hide a div when two dropdown option selected also with button click

Tags: jquery

hy all I want two show the div only on when a user selects two dropdown values and after that click the button. I want to compare the values on which base I will show a div after the button click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    if (($(this).val() == 'bfcn') && ($(this).siblings('select').val() == 'bfcn')) {
      $('.bfcn').show();
    } else {
      $('.bfcn').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formShow" onsubmit="javascript: return false;">
  <select title="Select 1" id="select1">
    <option value="">Select an op`enter code here`tion</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="bfcn">bfcn</option>
  </select>
  <select title="Select 2" id="select2">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="bfcn">bfcn</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" id="button1" value="click" />
  <p class="bfcn">BFCN</p>
</form>
```

Comment: "also with button click" - not quite sure what this means, but looks like you just need to move your existing code to the button click event handler (with some minor changes to change `this`)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is in place, you simply need to change the event handler to listen for a click on `#button1`, and then select the `select` elements directly instead of using the `this` reference and traversing the DOM to find the sibling.

Also note that you can simplify the logic by providing a boolean value to `toggle()` instead of an `if` condition. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.bfcn').toggle($('#select1').val() == 'bfcn' && $('#select2').val() == 'bfcn');
  });
});
```

```css
.bfcn { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formShow">
  <select title="Select 1" id="select1">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="bfcn">bfcn</option>
  </select>
  <select title="Select 2" id="select2">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="bfcn">bfcn</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" id="button1" value="click" />
  <p class="bfcn">BFCN</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to you my dear friend i am very thankful to you for your this cooperation respect to your work!!

Comment: Hey dear i want to do it for many dropdown values options so what i should do??

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean as your code was originally working in that way